# Increase delay and load over time in jMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to get an increase in delay/pause and load over time in jmeter load testing while keeping the sequence constant. For example -

- Initially - 10 samples (of 2 get requests - a,b,a,b,a,b...)
- Then after 10 samples, a delay/pause of 10 secs and then 20 samples (a,b,a,b,a,b...)
- After the 20 samples, another delay/pause of 20 secs; then 30 samples (a,b,a,b,a,b...)

And so on.

Constraints here being -

- Getting exact number of samples
- Getting the desired delay
- The order of requests should be maintained

The critical section controller helps with maintaining the order of threads but only in a normal thread group. So if I try the ultimate thread group to get the desired variable delay and load, the order and number of samples go haywire.

I've tried the following-

- Run test group consecutively
- Flow control action
- Throughput controller
- Module controller
- Interleave controller
- Synchronizing timer (with and without flow control)
- Add think times to children

Is there any way to get this output in jMeter? Or should I just opt for scripting?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) and set the following variables there:

   ```
   samples=10
   delay=10
   ```

   [image]
2. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and specify the required number of threads and iterations
3. Add [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) under the Thread Group and set "Loop Count" to `${samples}`. Put your requests under the Loop Controller

   [image]
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put the following code into Script area:

   ```
   def delay = vars.get('delay') as long

   sleep(delay * 1000)

   def new_delay = delay + 10

   vars.put('delay', new_delay as String)

   def samples = vars.get('samples') as int

   def new_samples = samples + 10

   vars.put('samples', new_samples as String)
   ```

   [image]